# Is EventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(aMessage) the same as EventAggregator.Publish(aMessage,Execute.OnUIThread)?

Tags: caliburn.micro

Micro 2.x users,

I'm having trouble mocking (using moq) and verifying a call to EventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread since it is a extension method!

Poking around in the source code made me come up with another method call that IS mockable :-)

But it would be nice to know if EventAggregator.Publish(aMessage,Execute.OnUIThread)
is the equivalent of EventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread(aMessage)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent.

This is how the `EventAggregator.PublishOnUIThread` extension method is currently implemented:

```
public static void PublishOnUIThread(this IEventAggregator eventAggregator, object message)
{
    eventAggregator.Publish(message, Execute.OnUIThread);
}
```

For details, see the [EventAggregatorExtensions.cs](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/blob/master/src/Caliburn.Micro/EventAggregatorExtensions.cs) source code.